# How do I monitor runtime upgrades with sidecar?

Tags: runtime, upgrade, opengov

We need to monitor the spec version of the block, that is, the runtime upgrade.

Of course, we know that openGov's suggestions will determine the upgrade.

So we're going to run this [guide](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-runtime-upgrades#monitoring-runtime-changes) to monitor this.

But there's a problem. For the life of me, I can't figure out which key to put as a query param here.

```
{sidecar host}/pallets/democracy/storage/ReferendumInfoOf?at=17506425&keys[]=1
```

For example, if you make a request like the one above get a response like the one below. I can't find anything about democracy.

```
 {
        "at": {
            "hash": "0x6509ec5addbe481a8f66aac9dac7c22342039c9521225b8e455c156871304653",
            "height": "17506425"
        },
        "pallet": "democracy",
        "palletIndex": "14",
        "storageItem": "referendumInfoOf",
        "keys": [
            "1"
        ],
        "value": {
            "finished": {
                "approved": true,
                "end": "1003528"
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd rather crawl the openGov site, but that's not easy either, because there's no single section where suggestions for runtime upgrades are posted.

So my question is this.

1. I want to use sidecar to view proposals in democracy, what is the 'key for storage' and where can I find it? What should I query?
2. Aren't proposal for runtime upgrades submitted to a set section of openGov site?
   I ask this question because recent updates have been suggested in other sections.

- v9431 upgrade : submit to [referenda section](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referenda/166)
- v9370 upgrade : submit to [motion section](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/motion/354)

Thank you in advance. Also, if there are any runtime upgrade monitoring methods you know of, recommendations would be appreciated.